# Creating all possible combinations of attributes ,configurable product magento

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I have a configurable product with multiple attributes.

I need to create every possible combination of associated products for this configurable product. The reason being that I do not have the option of using Custom Options (related to another question).

Since Magento takes these attributes in hierarchical order, and there are 5 configuration options each having 5 (let's say) values.

e.g.

Option A - with values A1, A2,A3,A4,A5

Option B - with values B1, B2,B3,B4,B5

…. and so on till E

So I will have to manually create 5^5 = 3125 options.

Is there a simple way to create these simple/associated products ? Can this also be done through a DB query ? The options would more or less remain fixed at the moment.

If it is simple to create these through a query, which all tables will be needed for this in Magento  ?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend modifying the database directly, unless you are 100% absolutely sure you know what you're doing.

Your best bet is probably going to be doing a CSV import. Create all the simple products (options) you need in an Excel spreadsheet, save as a CSV, and go to System > Import/Export > Import in your Magento backend. You can create your simple products and associate them to the configurable product with this method.

If you need an example of the format this needs to be in, manually create a configurable product and a few simple ones to associate it with. Then go to System > Import/Export > Export to download a CSV of the products. This will show you the proper format.

Comment: Thanks William for your advise

Comment: I got an extension to create all possible combination of simple products for configurable products.http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-products-generator-6861.html

Its a great extension for those who want to create complex configurable product.

Thanks,Irphan